# ELK Prompting to upgrade java version even after upgraded to latest on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04, elastic-stack, elk

I'm using ELasticsearch on ubuntu 18.04 (AWS). While i try to run "./elasticsearch-setup-passwords" script it is showing following error.

> future versions of Elasticsearch will require Java 11; your Java
> version from [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre] does not meet
> this requirement

But while I check for Jaa version it shows Java 11.

```
root@ip-162-41-63-148:/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin# java -version
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I upgrade Java from 8 to 11.

Why still this problem occur? And how to fix it?

Comment: You have more than one Java installed. Uninstall all except the latest one. find / -name java can help

Answer (score 2):

JAVA_HOME was still set to Java 8 jre folder. So I change the JAVA_HOME path to java 11 then it was working fine.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```